# Unity/C# - Is it possible to connect an Azure (cloud) database, to a Unity game, via EnityFramework?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, azure, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity game that requires a cloud database.  (Where you can connect to a database from inside of the game.)

It doesn't need to anything crazy.  Mostly just reading & writing simple columns in a table, and maybe a simple login.

Is this possible to do in Unity using the Entity Framework?

If not, are there any workarounds?  (e.g. Using MySQL instead)

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Benji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?gclid=Cj0KEQiA-_HDBRD2lomhoufc1JkBEiQA0TVMmvG30xxPW72XEW3zsXBcaBXOYtoJHreE4m1xEWPxZ54aAh3V8P8HAQ). Basic steps are:

- Add [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) to the project.
- Create a Firebase project in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).
- Download the config file from Firebase Console. The file for Unity3D might be one or both of the below files: GoogleService-Info.plist (for iOS), Google-services.json (for Android)

Then you can access the data manipulation with simple snippet as below:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class MyScript: MonoBehaviour {
  void Start() {
    // Set this before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/");
    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
  }
}
```

The data will be in the form of as below, for example.
[image]

Writing data to db:

```
private void writeNewUser(string userId, string name, string email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);

    reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

Reading data:

```
reference.GetReference("users")
         .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
             if (task.IsFaulted) {

             }
             else if (task.IsCompleted) {          
               // Do something with snapshot...
             }
  });
```

What is even cool is that Firebase supports user authentication (i.e. logins) and more, which is very handy to Unity3D developers.

A tutorial on how to link Unity3D with Firebase is [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2017/01/16/firebase-unity3d-example-a-walk-through-tutorial/), though it is not using Firebase database, but Firebase messaging as an example, it might be useful to get you started there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, and yes, Firebase is a **great** solution if you need real-time/live data.  (like player positions in a multiplayer online game)

However, there's a better (free) approach, if all you need a simple stuff.  (like saving a player's high score, and displaying it)

(At least that's all I really needed, so here's what I did)

**Step 1)** Create your database (Azure, or whatever)

**Step 2)** Make a website/app, host it, and connect your DB.

**Step 3)** Add API "endpoints" to your app.  (which interact with your DB)

**Step 4)** Use Unity's "**WWW**" class to interact (make RESTful GETs/POSTs) to your endpoints.

And that's it!
Works like a CHARM, for me!  (pretty fast, too!)

Comment: and how do you prevent someone from decompiling your app to get the API credentials of your app such as your app secret?  With that, they will be able to call your APIs and possibly steal data.
Firebase has a security model built in to support validation rules with 3rd party auth that lets you completely control what users have access to different parts of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase developer here.  Thanks for the plug David.

You can find more documentation including a guide for working with the Firebase Realtime Database and Unity [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start)